# Using Bootstrap tab view in Django

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement tabs using Django and Bootstrap.
The following code does not switch tabs properly. Tab switching is not working even thought URL is changing
Please let me know how I can switch tabs without any problems.

Code

```
        <div class = "company-info-tab">
            <div class="container">
              <!-- Nav tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Baby computer Man</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <!-- Tab panes -->
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">A "Hello, World!" program generally is a computer program that outputs or displays the message "Hello, World!". Such a program is very simple in most programming languages, and is often used to illustrate the basic syntax of a programming language. It is often the first program written by people learning to code.</div>
                <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu1">The Manchester Baby, also known as the Small-Scale Experimental Machine, was the world's first electronic stored-program computer. It was built at the University of Manchester, UK, by Frederic C. Williams, Tom Kilburn, and Geoff Tootill, and ran its first program on 21 June 1948, seventy-one years ago</div>
                <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu2">...</div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

Screen

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add "show" class on your active tab:

```
  <div class = "company-info-tab">
        <div class="container">
          <!-- Nav tabs -->
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Baby computer Man</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- Tab panes -->
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane container show active" id="home">A "Hello, World!" program generally is a computer program that outputs or displays the message "Hello, World!". Such a program is very simple in most programming languages, and is often used to illustrate the basic syntax of a programming language. It is often the first program written by people learning to code.</div>
            <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu1">The Manchester Baby, also known as the Small-Scale Experimental Machine, was the world's first electronic stored-program computer. It was built at the University of Manchester, UK, by Frederic C. Williams, Tom Kilburn, and Geoff Tootill, and ran its first program on 21 June 1948, seventy-one years ago</div>
            <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="menu2">...</div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```